# Rails form issuing GET request instead of POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am making a Rails 3.1 app and have a signup form that was working fine, but I seemed to have changed something to break it.. I'm using Twitter bootstrap and twitter_bootstrap_form_for gem. I made some change that messed with the formatting of the form fields, but more importantly, when I submit the Sign Up form to create a new User, the information is showing up in the URL and looks like this:

EDIT: This is happening in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox

http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=UaKG5Y8fuPul2Klx7e2LtdPLTRepBxDM3Zdy8S%2F52W4%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=kevinc%40example.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=testing&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=testing&commit=Sign+Up

Here is the code for the form:

```
    <div class="span7">
      <h3 class="center" id="more">Sign Up Now!</h3>
        <%= twitter_bootstrap_form_for @user do |user| %>
      <%= user.email_field :email, :placeholder => 'me@example.com' %>
      <%= user.password_field :password %>
      <%= user.password_field :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password' %>
          <%= user.actions do %>
        <%= user.submit 'Sign Up' %>
      <% end %>
        <% end %>
   </div>
```

Here is the code for the UsersController:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def new
       @user = User.new
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
         redirect_to about_path, :notice => "Signed up!"
        else
         render 'new'
        end
       end
     end
```

Not sure if there is more you need but if so let me know! Thank you!

Edit: For debugging I tried specifying :post and also using a plain form_for

```
     <%= form_for(@user, :method => :post) do |f| %>
         <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
          </div>        
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></div>
      <% end %>
```

This gives me the same problem as above.

Adding routes.rb:

```
    Auth31::Application.routes.draw do

     get "home"     => "pages#home"
     get "about"    => "pages#about"
     get "contact"  => "pages#contact"
     get "help"     => "pages#help"
     get "login"    => "sessions#new",     :as => "login"
     get "logout"   => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
     get "signup"   => "users#new",        :as => "signup"
     root :to       => "pages#home"

     resources :pages
     resources :users
     resources :sessions
     resources :password_resets
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was specifying the HTML form tag when Rails form_for generates its own. See below to add a class to a form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-stacked"} )  do |f| %>
```

This worked fine. I'm still not sure why having 2  tags would generate a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your for is sending a GET request, rather that a POST request. I'm not sure why this is happening (have you tried using plain `form_for` for debugging purposes?), but you should be able to fix it my explicitly setting the method:

```
<%= twitter_bootstrap_form_for(@user, :method => :post) do |user| %>
```

Comment: I tried specifying :post to no avail. And I tried using a a plain form_for. Adding the code above as an edit if you don't mind taking a look. Still having the same issue..

Comment: No problem, I made an edit because I realized I sounded a bit snarky :)