# Ruby - Saving a Model shows a Get url in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, save

- Ruby 2.2.4
- Rails 4.2.6
- PostgreSQL 9.5

I am trying to save a simple model, but when I submit the form, my browser url shows this "http://localhost:8080/notes/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=z0cyVNfUKYWDSDASDWFFZ96zj29UTtDYe8dLlKrI6Mbznb2SrTWNm%2BQ91D2s2AASD2345Fl3fTOneCC2dNg%3D%3D&note%5Btitulo%5D=ddddddd&note%5Bconteudo%5D=dddddddddddddddddd&commit=Create"

I am curious about this because other project, it has the same methods, same routes, the only difference is the model that only have one column, but it works fine.

```
def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
      t.text :titulo
      t.text :conteudo
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

My controller: notes_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @note = Note.new
  end

  def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params)
    if @note.save
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:titulo,:conteudo)
    end
```

my form

```
<%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :titulo %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :titulo %>
          <%= f.label :conteudo %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :conteudo %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Create" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'notes#index'
  get 'notes/new' => 'notes#new'
  post 'notes' => 'notes#create'
```

I saw this post [Rails form issuing GET request instead of POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098491/rails-form-issuing-get-request-instead-of-post-request)

but does not work for me.

Edit:

I fix it thanks to Anthony E, his answer made me look back to code and realize that I have a form inside a form. The outer form was in application.html.erb.

Thanks to all.

Comment: can you please share the HTML form tag that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails can't infer the appropriate form route from your model. Try explicitly setting the form URL and submit method in your `form_for`:

```
form_for @note, url: "/notes", as: :note, html: { method: :post } do |f|
end
```

Alternatively, it may be simpler to use resourceful routing:

**In routes.rb:**

```
resources :notes, only: [:new, :create, :index]
```

This will create the following routes:

```
GET /notes/new  # Maps to NotesController#new
POST /notes     # Maps to NotesController#create
GET /notes      # Maps to NotesController#index
```

Comment: I don't think it should matter, as long as Rails has a way of associating a model with a route. You can check this by verifying `url_for(<object>)`. For instance `url_for(Note)` should return `/notes`. It's actually simpler if the resources aren't nested.